# How to inject data into QT item shown with loader

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

In my application I have a global system that handles navigation between "screens". In QML I can simply call something like:

```
appNavigation.show("MyScreen.qml", NavigationType.FADE)
```

this calls a C++ part of the code which handles the current stack of screens and uses signals to report back to QML to do the actual animation. At the end in QML some `Loader` will load the input qml ("MyScreen.qml" in this case) and show it as defined.

My issue here is how to inject data into newly loaded screen. Essentially I would like to do something like the following:

```
function showMyScreen() {
    MyScreen screen = appNavigation.show("MyScreen.qml", NavigationType.FADE)
    screen.someData = "some data here"
}
```

but is this possible? Could I somehow return the screen that is loaded by the loader?

I am guessing not so I would satisfy with sending the data with the navigation itself like:

```
function showMyScreen() {
    MyScreen screen = appNavigation.show("MyScreen.qml", NavigationType.FADE, "some data here")
}
```

I could forward the data to the point where I set source to the loader but still what then? How or where would that specific screen that is going to be loaded get the data. To reduce is this is what I get:

```
function setNewItemWithData(newItem, data) {
    loader.source = newItem
    loader.concreteScreen.data = data // Not really doable
}
```

again I assume this is not doable and I need to forward the data down to loader and use `onLoaded` event. So what I would do is something like:

```
onLoaded: {
    myLoadedScreen.data = data
}
```

I assume something like this is possible but how? What am I missing here, how do I get `myLoadedScreen` and how to access its properties?

What I am currently doing now is dumping the data in C++ part and then collecting it in the loaded QML. So like the following:

```
appNavigation.injectedData = "some data here"
```

and then in the newly loaded item:

```
property data = appNavigation.injectedData
```

It works but this seems like extremely poor coding. Any of the alternatives would be helpful.

Thank you for your patience.

**Since the request for MCVE was made:**

This is a general problem and I expect it to have multiple solutions. I would be looking forward to any of them. However the minimal example to produce this is creating a new project and adding a loader with another qml to which some property should be changed:

main:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Loader {
        anchors.fill: parent; anchors.margins: 20
        source: "MyScreen.qml"
        // TODO: make screen green (loadedScreen.color = "green")
    }
}
```

MyScreen:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    color: "red"
}
```

Current result is seeing a red rectangle and desired result is to see a green one. The point being that the main screen needs to tell what color the loaded screen needs to use.

Comment: That would be great if you can provide mvce, at least `appNavigation.show` source.

Comment: @folibis Please see if added information is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [item](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html#item-prop) property of the Loader to get the object loaded:

```
Loader {
    id: loader
    anchors.fill: parent; anchors.margins: 20
    source: "MyScreen.qml"
    onLoaded: loader.item.color = "green"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you might as well use [`Component`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html) (If you use it when reacting to an event)

```
Component {
    id: myScreenComponent
    MyScreen {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}

function showMyScreen() {
    myScreenComponent.createObject(this, {"color: "green"});
}
```

Alternatively, given your first code, I would recommend you to use [`StackView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html).
The [`push` method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html#push-method) seems to be similar to your `appNavigation.show` one.
You can give it an url, some properties, and a transition type (that you can customize).

Comment: But component must be in the same scope, right? I can not just use this in any qml file. I guess I could create a component for every screen I have but I would rather see that is not the case. Still the "createObject" method looks promising since it accepts properties that are set to top object. StackView is not an option at the moment unfortunately but I do see it does provide interface to inject data into it.